# Unwind in storyboard crashes

Tags: ios, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

I'm writing an app with multiple (3) views.  If I unwind twice from 3 to 2 to 1 the last unwind crashes the app with this message:

> ABGViewController setResultE1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x751d4b0'

ResultE1 is a label on the 3rd view. This does not happen if I cancel the destination into the second segue. What is happening? I cannot realize where the conflict is.

This is the first segue (here is the unwind that crashes, but does not crash if I delete view 3rd):

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender: (id)sender
{
    ResultsABGViewController *destination=[segue destinationViewController];       
    {
        if (na<135)
        {
            destination.Result4=@"Hypo";
        } 
    }
}
```

This is the second segue (the one that if the `if _lbl....resultE1` is cancelled the error does not happen, but it works if I delete the 3rd view. It calls ResultE1 which seems to cause the crash):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ElectrolytesViewController *destination=[segue destinationViewController];

    if (_lblResult4.text=@"Hypo")
    {
      destination.ResultE1=@"yyy";
    }
}
```